# Does it make sense to contact potential PhD supervisors after having submitted the application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, application, italy

I already submitted my application and they are about to start interviews, however learning more about the faculty I found a potential supervisor and I would like to know whether there are chances they are interested in having me doing that kind of research (understanding whether he will accept supervisees or other colleagues that have same interests will).

Comment: What country is this? I think the answer depends on the place.

Comment: @Buffy It is Italy

Comment: Thanks. We have a few Italian academia here who can probably provide the most specific advice. Not me, alas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Standards vary but from my experience, it can be seen as trying to influence your chance of admission.

Generally speaking, if you want to contact faculty before getting accepted, the appropriate time to contact them is *before* submitting your application (and even then, it's not uncommon to be turned down).

Again, standards vary and I'm sure some faculty are fine with it, but the general impression I've gotten (at least in US universities) is that it's often considered inappropriate during the admissions process and you should wait until a decision is made.

Comment: You're making the assumption that the potential supervisor even responds to emails from prospective students.